# Ember sub route appending empty record to collection

Tags: ember.js

Sub route appending empty record to collection I've got a bit of a tricky problem and I'm hoping you peeps can help.

This works as expected BUT if I refresh the page with a location sub route the locations list gets an empty record appended to the end.

```
App.Router.map ->
    this.resource 'home', { path: '/' }
    this.resource 'locations', ->
        this.resource 'location', { path: ':slug' }
    this.resource 'services'
    this.resource 'contact'
    this.resource 'login'

App.LocationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
        this.store.find 'location'

App.LocationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    serialize: (model, params)->
        slug: model.get 'slug'

    model: (params)->
        this.store.find 'location', params.slug
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the json returned from both ajax calls?